# Creating functions to define password characteristics?

Tags: javascript, variables, passwords, generator, prompt

I am working on a random password generator that uses prompts from the user to create a password based on the parameters the user defined. I, so far, have the prompts working and logging the correct responses, but I am just starting to learn javascript and am a bit confused on where to go next. I don't know how to combine the variables for possible password characters, and the variables of the user response. Any help is appreciated! Here is the code I have so far:

```js
var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");
// Variables that could possibly be included, based on the user responses
var caps = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
var lower = ["a", "b", "c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
var num = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
var spec = ['@', '%', '+', '', '/', "'", '!', '#', '$', '^', '?', ':', ',', ')', '(', '}', '{', ']', '[', '~', '-', '_', '.']
// Write password to the #password input

function generatePassword () {
  //Attributing variables based on user responses
var pwLength; 
 pwLength = prompt ("How many characters in your password? Please choose between 8-24.")
  if ((pwLength < 24) && (pwLength > 8)) {
    console.log (pwLength);
  }
  else {
    alert ("Please use characters between 8-24.");
    return false;
  };
var pwCaps 
  pwCaps = confirm("Would you like to include uppercase letters?")
  if (confirm){
    console.log (pwCaps);
};
var pwSpec 
  pwSpec = confirm("Would you like to include special characters?")
  if (confirm){
    console.log (pwSpec);
  };
  //Creating the length, case style, and character inclusion of the password based on the above variables
```

Comment: Did you come up with a conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```js
function checkPassStrength(pass){

    let passwordVariations = {
        length: pass.length >= 8,
        digits: /\d/.test(pass),
        lower: /[a-z]/.test(pass),
        upper: /[A-Z]/.test(pass),
        nonWords: /\W/.test(pass),
        strength: 'Weak',
        progress: 10
    }

    let variationCount = 0;
    for (var check in passwordVariations) {
        variationCount += (passwordVariations[check] === true) ? 1 : 0;
    }

    if (variationCount === 5) {
        passwordVariations.progress = variationCount * 20
        passwordVariations.strength = "Excellent"
        return passwordVariations;
    }
    if (variationCount === 4) {
        passwordVariations.progress = variationCount * 20
        passwordVariations.strength = "Good"
        return passwordVariations;
    }
    if (variationCount === 3) {
        passwordVariations.progress = variationCount * 20
        passwordVariations.strength = "Average"
        return passwordVariations;
    }
    if (variationCount <= 2) {
        passwordVariations.progress = variationCount * 20
        passwordVariations.strength = "Weak"
        return passwordVariations;
    }
}

let result = checkPassStrength('Pass@123')
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's divide your question into two major parts.

1. **Concatenating arrays and select random elements from them**
2. **Conditional concatenating**

---

### Concatenating set of arrays

In the first place let's say you want to allow all your characters to be included in your password pattern, so **you just have to combine all set of characters with either [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) or more elegant way by [spread syntax (spread operator)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)** which is available in ES6+.

I will go with the second approach and its results would be something like this (so simple isn't it?):

```js
allowedCharacters = [...lower, ...num, ...caps, ...spec]
```

Then you just have to select random elements from your array by selecting random indexes. So it's simply achievable with using `Math.random() * allowedCharacters.length` where **`Math.random()` will generate a random number** (in range of `0-1` and its include `0` also) and **`allowedCharacters.length` is the length of our `allowedCharacter` array**. Since the **result of the previous calculation will be decimal so we need to use `Math.floor`** in order to get a round number (integer). So the product of this calculation will give us a random index in our combined array.

The final output of above will be:

```js
Math.floor(Math.random() * allowedCharacters.length)
```

The only thing that remains here is iteration based on the provided length of the password. It can simply achievable with traditional [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop.

So it will look like this at the end:

```js
const caps = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
const lower = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
const num = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
const spec = ['@', '%', '+', '', '/', "'", '!', '#', '$', '^', '?', ':', ',', ')', '(', '}', '{', ']', '[', '~', '-', '_', '.']
const allowedCharacters = [...lower, ...num, ...caps, ...spec]

function createPassword(length) {
  let password = ''

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    password += allowedCharacters[Math.floor(Math.random() * allowedCharacters.length)]
  }

  return password
}

const button = document.getElementById('generate')

button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  const input = document.getElementById('length')

  if (input.value > 0) {
    console.log('Generated password is: ', createPassword(input.value))
  } else {
    console.log('Enter the valid positive number!')
  }
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" id="length" placeholder="enter the length of desired password" min="1" />
  <button id="generate">generate</button>
</form>
```

### Conditional concatenating

But then you want to get Items from the desired set of characters, so **you can make your concatenate conditional with the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)**. We can simply pass truthy or falsy values to our previously implemented function and then make a condition on whether to include each set of characters.

For example, let's say we want to know to make our lower array concatenating conditional. Assume `lowerIncluded` is our condition so when it be `true` we will add our lower array to our `allowedCharacters` array and when it be `false` we will add an empty array instead (It won't append anything to our final array).

It will be something like this:

```js
allowedCharacters = [...(lowerIncluded ? lower : [])]
```

So your final code should be something like this:

```js
const caps = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
const lower = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
const num = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
const spec = ['@', '%', '+', '', '/', "'", '!', '#', '$', '^', '?', ':', ',', ')', '(', '}', '{', ']', '[', '~', '-', '_', '.']


function createPassword(length, lowerIncluded, capsIncluded, numIncluded, specIncluded) {
  let password = ''
  const allowedCharacters = [...(lowerIncluded ? lower : []), ...(numIncluded ? num : []), ...(capsIncluded ? caps : []), ...(specIncluded ? spec : [])]
  const allowedCharactersLength = allowedCharacters.length

  if (allowedCharactersLength > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      password += allowedCharacters[Math.floor(Math.random() * allowedCharactersLength)]
    }

    return password
  } else {
    return "You didn't select any allowed character set!"
  }
}


const button = document.getElementById('generate')

button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  const input = document.getElementById('length')
  const lowerCharacters = document.getElementById('lowerCharacters')
  const capsCharacters = document.getElementById('capsCharacters')
  const numCharacters = document.getElementById('numCharacters')
  const specCharacters = document.getElementById('specCharacters')

  if (input.value > 0) {
    console.log('Generated password is: ', createPassword(input.value, lowerCharacters.checked, capsCharacters.checked, numCharacters.checked, specCharacters.checked))
  } else {
    console.log('Enter the valid positive number!')
  }
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" id="length" placeholder="enter the length of desired password" min="1" />
  <button id="generate">generate</button>
  <div>
    <label for="lowerCharacters">lower</label>
    <input id="lowerCharacters" type="checkbox" checked/>
    <label for="capsCharacters">caps</label>
    <input id="capsCharacters" type="checkbox" checked/>
    <label for="numCharacters">num</label>
    <input id="numCharacters" type="checkbox" checked/>
    <label for="specCharacters">spec</label>
    <input id="specCharacters" type="checkbox" checked/>
  </div>
</form>
```

**NOTE:** This implementation is not the best or even the smartest way, so it just exists for simplicity and more illustration, so it will give you a vision of what should you do in your scenario.